# how do I concatenate sub strings to make a bigger string

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Specifically, I am trying to build up the following statement and run it as the following command:

```
system("java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass 1234567890 98765");
```

I have researched this online, but the examples did not compile, so I pieced together the following illustrative pseudo code.  **How do I change the code below to get it to concatenate the string and execute the command?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char jv[33];
    strcpy(jv, "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass ");
    char to[10];
    strcpy(to, "1234567890 ");
    char pin[5];
    strcpy(pin, "98765");
    system(jv + to + pin);
}
```

`to` and `pin` are arguments sent to a java program.  Eventually, `to` and `pin` will be coming from inputs, but for now I just want to treat them as these values while I test other pieces of the code.

Comment: try `snprintf`snprintf(buf, bufsize, "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass %d %d", 1234567890, 98765)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snprintf()` is a flexible and a safe method.  [@fukanchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655436/fukanchik).  The main challenge in C is to:
1) manage string memory space and
2) prevent overruns.

```
const char *jv = "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass ";
const char *to = "1234567890 ";
const char *pin = "98765";

#define BIGBUF 100
char command[BIGBUF];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "%s%s%s", jv, to, pin);
system(command);
```

Or with C99 and assuming integers

```
const char *jv = "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass";
long to = 1234567890;
long pin = 98765;
int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %ld %ld", jv, to, pin);
char command[n+1];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "%s %ld %ld", jv, to, pin);
system(command);
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for writing code that is human readable in line with the logic that I defined in the OP.  I am glad that I waited instead of prematurely accepting one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

From an actual command line, like int main (int argc, char **argv)

```
char buf[1024] = {0};
int n;
for (n = 0; n < argc; n ++)
  strcat (buf, argv[n]); // Change to strlcat if you have it available (BSD or Mac)
printf ("result = %s\n", buf);
```

Or using your example:

```
char jv[33];
strcpy(jv, "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass ");
char to[10];
strcpy(to, "1234567890 ");
char pin[5];
strcpy(pin, "98765");
system(jv + to + pin);


char result[1024] = {0}; // C does not zero format variables inside a function, so we do it ourselves with = {0}
sprintf (result, "%s %s %s", jv, to, pin); // Should use snprintf instead if available
printf ("result = %s\n", result);
```

OR

```
char result[1024] =  {0};
strcat (result, jv);
strcat (result, " ");
strcat (result, to);
strcat (result, " ");
strcat (result, pin); // Should use strlcat instead if available
printf ("result = %s\n", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me tell you the mistakes in above code.

```
char jv[33];
strcpy(jv, "java -cp . mainpackage.SomeClass ");
```

in `C`, strings are null-terminated, so you'll be needing an extra element per string to store the null. Expand the size of your array.

The, for concatenation like

```
system(jv + to + pin);
```

you can define an array **large enough** to hold the concatenated final value and use [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) to concatenate the source and destination string. You can use a loop, to append more than one sub-string to make a complete command-string, as you want.

Comment: Wow - I can't believe that the OP addded up all the chars and sized the array, (nearly), exactly.   Why do devs do this?  What is wrong with char array[256]'??

Comment: @MartinJames I would say (_mis_)sized. And just my gut feeling, most of the OP's doing this are not "devs", no offence if otherwise :)